# Dumb quotes into smart quotes only for text not HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, replace, quotes

I’m transforming dumb quotes into smart quotes in a `contenteditable` but the problem is that it also replaces them inside HTML elements like:

```
<a href=“something” title=“something”
```

thus making them invalid. I want to only do it for user’s text. Here’s the catch. I have to keep the original formatting elements, so I can’t do something like:

```
clean($('#something_container').text());
```

This would remove all HTML elements (formatting) when returned. Here’s the code that I have:

```
content = clean($('#post_content').html());
$('#post_content').html(content);

// replaces ", ', --, <div> with <p>
function clean(html) {
  html = html.replace(/'\b/g, "\u2018")  // opening singles
         .replace(/\b'/g, "\u2019")  // closing singles
         .replace(/"\b/g, "\u201c")  // opening doubles
         .replace(/\b"/g, "\u201d")  // closing doubles
         .replace(/--/g,  "\u2014") // em-dashes
         .replace(/<div>/g, "<p>")  //<div> to <p>
         .replace(/<\/div>/g, "</p>"); //</div> to </p>
  return html;
};
```

What would be the best (most efficient) way to replace dumb quotes only in user’s text and skip the HTML tags like `<img src="" />`? Thanks!

Comment: Note that replacing `<div>` won't catch DIVs with attributes, such as  `<div class="...">`. Also, it should be `</p>` in the very last `replace`.

Comment: @fanaugen oops, fixed it. I don’t care for classes, just <div> that get inserted in by some browsers when changing formatting (ex. from <ul> to <p>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a possible approach (don’t know about efficiency, but if you only handle strings typed in by users by hand, they probably won’t be very long, so it shouldn’t matter):

1. split your string into non-overlapping chunks: HTML tags vs. the rest
2. “educate quotes” only in the non-tags, leaving the tags alone
3. put the string back together

If the HTML you’re dealing with is well-formed (in particular, if there’s no "`<`" floating around), the splitting into chunks is easy:

```
var html   = '<p style="color:red">some "quotes" in here</p>'
var chunks = html.match(/(<.+?>|[^<]+)/g)
// returns Array: ['<p style="color:red">', 'some "quotes" in here', '</p>']
```

Then, given your `clean()` function that handles the replacements, you can say:

```
cleaned = chunks.map(function(chunk){
  return /</.test(chunk) ? chunk : clean(chunk)
}).join('');
```

to apply your replacements anywhere except between `<` and `>`.